# How to remove dot dot slash from string?

Tags: php

I want to remove all dot dot slashes in the URL string so user doesn't have access to parent level directory. What I could have is `../../../file`, is the below approach safe to use?

```
$str = '../../../file';
$str = str_replace('..','', ltrim($str,'/'));
```

EDIT: Thanks for your suggestions and answers, but I also like to know why NOT to use this code? Is it not safe enough? Can it be exploited?

Comment: Why not use pathinfo() or basename()? Perhaps realpath() might also work.

Comment: you can use pathinfo().

Answer (score 2):

You can use preg_replace like this:

```
$string = '../../../file';
echo preg_replace("/(\.\.\/)/","", $string);
```

Comment: thanks, but is my approach safe? can user exploit it in any way which I am not fore-seeing?

Comment: @MagExt Your approach will not work in some cases:

e..g: '../../../folder/file'

Comment: It is not necessary (and is overkill) to use regex when you are implementing a completely literal search string. Just use `str_replace()` or `strtr()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '../../../file';
$str = str_replace('../','', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: thanks, but is my approach safe? can user exploit it in any way which I am not fore-seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear with your question, I suspect you need to rewrite your URLs.
if it so you can rewrite it by using .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1
```

Or you just want to remove sub-folders from $str alone 
you just use the below code

```
$str = preg_replace('/..\//', '',  $str);
```

or

```
$str = str_replace('../','', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do using multiple character select :

```
echo str_replace(array('..', '/'), ' ', $string);
```